# Force Cast button to show?

Tags: java, android, chromecast, showcaseview

I am implementing the Chromecast SDK into my Android application and I'd like to know if it's at all possible to make the Cast button appear regardless of whether there are available cast routes available?

Currently, the SDK works by hiding the button until it find a viable route to cast to.

However, I want to show the user some on screen instructions, and need the button to be there from the start, so they can see what it looks like.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use MediaRouteButton and then you can manage its visibility yourself. However, that is not the right experience; you should tie the appearance of your "instructions" to when the cast button shows up; if cast button doesn't show up, don't show any instructions since that will confuse user anyway. You can look at the CastVideos-android app which does that.

Comment: I found the code in CastVideo-android, but the method onCastDeviceDetected is part of the Video Cast implementation. is there a default method for detecting when routes are available?

Comment: onCastDeviceDetected() is part of CCL not Cast Videos. If you do not want to use CCL, then you can listen for device discovery messages from the SDK (and cache) the number of devices that are discovered and go from there.

Comment: More specifically it's part of the CCL that is designed for video casting, that was my point.

Comment: Not at all; that part doesn't care if it is related to video or not; I don't know why you think it is related to casting video; that callback is related to device discovery so has nothing to do with videos or something else.

Comment: Well I had a look at the code and it's an override of a method in VideoCastConsumerImpl. This led me to think it's a method only accessible if I used that, which I'm not.

Comment: Well, if you look carefully, you'll see that it is in BaseCastConsumerImpl. Anyhow, you don't have to use that or CCL for that matter, you can do your own work.